# How to select random columns from a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset like:

```
ID  val1    val2    val3    val4
1   4       9       10      16
2   1.5     6       2.3     99
3   8       7       7       10
```

I would like to check whether the number of columns (i.e., `val` columns) is less than 6 and if that is the case, I want to randomly select the number of columns left from the existing columns and add them again to the dataset.

In the case above, the number of columns left is 2 (6 - 4 columns of val). In this case, I would like to select 2 random columns from the val columns and add them to the dataset. one possible solution would be:

```
ID  val1    val2    val3    val4   val2   val1
1   4       9       10      16     9      4
2   1.5     6       2.3     99     6      1.5
3   8       7       7       10     7      8
```

Columns `val2` and `val1` are randomly selected and added to the dataset.
The problem that I'm facing is how to select random columns. I know how to select random rows by using `sample_n` function, but I couldn't find any function to select random columns.

What I did so far is:

```
t <- read.csv("path", header=TRUE) # load file
numCols <- 6
cc <- ncol(t[,-1]) #no need for ID column
if(cc < numCols){
   # I need some function to select random columns 
}
```

Comment: `cbind(dat, dat[, sample(2:5, 2)])` or `dat[, c(1:ncol(dat), sample(2:ncol(dat), 2))]`

Comment: `df[, round(runif(1,0,6))`, adjust to your wanted columns

Comment: Same answer as @jogo (`n_wanted <- 15; n_current <- ncol(mtcars); cbind(mtcars, mtcars[, sample(n_current, n_wanted - n_current)])`). You just need to solve `ID` column problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dataframe is just a special kind of list, so you can think of it as selecting random *list elements* rather than columns. That means a random sample of two columns is as simple as `sample(df, 2)`. In your case you can keep things terse by  `cbind`ing a sample from `df[-1]`, assuming `ID` is the first column:

```r
nc <- 6 + 1 # val columns plus ID column

if(ncol(df) < nc){
    cbind(df, sample(df[-1], nc - ncol(df)))
}

#### OUTPUT ####

  ID val1 val2 val3 val4 val3 val2
1  1  4.0    9 10.0   16 10.0    9
2  2  1.5    6  2.3   99  2.3    6
3  3  8.0    7  7.0   10  7.0    7
```

If you don't know where `ID` is you could use something like `df[-grep("ID", names(df))]` instead of `df[-1]`. If there are other columns that are neither `ID` nor do they start with `val`, then you should use `df[grep("^val", names(df))]`. In the latter case you'll also need to make adjustments to `nc`, i.e. instead of just `1` you'll need to add the number of columns that don't start with `val`.

Answer (score 1):

We can make a function

```
add_columns <- function(df, n) {
   cols <- grep("val", names(df), value = TRUE)
   if (length(cols) < n)
     return(cbind(df, df[sample(cols, n - length(cols))]))
   return(df)
}

add_columns(df, 6)
#  ID val1 val2 val3 val4 val2 val1
#1  1  4.0    9 10.0   16    9  4.0
#2  2  1.5    6  2.3   99    6  1.5
#3  3  8.0    7  7.0   10    7  8.0

add_columns(df, 5)
#  ID val1 val2 val3 val4 val3
#1  1  4.0    9 10.0   16 10.0
#2  2  1.5    6  2.3   99  2.3
#3  3  8.0    7  7.0   10  7.0
```